# Ubuntu xfce need more disk space (Chromebook)

Tags: xfce, chromebook

I recently downloaded Ubuntu xfce4 4.12 for my Chromebook. It is running pretty smoothly and I want to make the full switch. Is there any way to allocate more disk space to xfce or just remove Chrome OS entirely?

Comment: yes : https://www.google.com/search?q=remove+chrome+os+from+chromebook&oq=remove+chrome+os+from+chromebook&aqs=chrome..69i57.8149j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=1

Answer (score 0):

I've used an sd card as "expanded" storage. I format it to Ext3 or FAT, and leave it in the slot. I point my downloads and other default save locations there. It helps when dealing with large files.

Comment: Please provide a more complete description of how to use an SD card as expanded storage on a Chromebook.